# Is it possible to define the mail's subject inside of the blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, email

When sending a mail using `Mail::queue` / `Mail::send` you have to pass a mail template and the subject separately.

Is there a way to manage the subject in the mail templates (better for multi-languages).

I.e. as the first line in the template

`mail.blade.php`

```
This is the subject
Hello User,
foobar
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to manage the subject line in the template itself? If you're doing this for multi-language support, that's what the resources/lang folder is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that hard:

```
    Mail::queue($template, $data, function (Message $message) use ($toUser, $sendingName, $sendingAddress) {
        // take subject from first line of the template
        $body = $message->getSwiftMessage()->getBody();
        $bodyLines = explode("\n", $body);
        if (count($bodyLines) == 0) {
            Log::warning('Empty mail');
            return;
        }
        $subject = $bodyLines[0];
        unset($bodyLines[0]);

        // send
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->setBody(implode("\n", $bodyLines));

        ....
```